# Dual Total Differential operator

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let $G$ acts on $M$ and $(t,x,u)\in M$, $g\in G$.
$$g.(t,x,u)=(T,X,U) $$
Let
$$T=t+\lambda_1\\
X=\lambda_3 t+ x +\lambda_1 \lambda_3 + \lambda_2\\
U=u+\lambda_3$$
where $u=u(x,t)$ and $\lambda_i$ are constants.

Then the total differential of $U$ respect to $T$ and $X$ is
$$U_T=D_T U= u_t-\lambda_3 u_x\\
U_X=D_X U=u_x$$

How these total derivatives is taken?

Comment: Your notation doesn't make clear which objects depend on which. I suggest to write down the domain and codomain of each map, so you can make things clear.

Comment: u(x,t). x,t are independent and u is dependant.

Comment: Where did you find this?, it might be easier to understand the question with the original context.

Comment: I founs it in "Olver, Lecture on moving frame". example 16.6

Comment: I'm afraid that is out of my scope, then. The author seems to have developed a variant of Cartan's method of moving frames, and the whole purpose of the paper is to explain what it is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above question, the ‎dual implicit ‎differential ‎operators ‎are ‎defined ‎as ‎follow‎
‎$$
D_{X^i}=\sum_{j=1}^p W^i_jD_{x^j},‎‎\quad W^j_i=(D_{x^j}X^i)^{-1}.
$$
where‎ ‎$D_{x^i}$ ‎is ‎the usual ‎total ‎derivative‎.‎